# Sum of random vectors with fixed amplitudes

Tags: distributions, estimation, density-function, circular-statistics

Is there a simple way to evaluate the pdf of the amplitude of a sum of vectors with fixed amplitudes and random phases?

Explicitly, let $Ae^{i\phi}=\sum_{n=1}^NA_ne^{i\phi_n}$, where $N$ is a fixed positive integer, the $A_n$ are fixed positive real numbers, and the $\phi_n$ are independently uniformly distributed over $[0,2\pi)$. Then $A$ is the non-negative real magnitude of the sum, and $\phi$ is a phase that I don't care about. Is there a simple expression for the pdf of $A$? (Or equivalently, a simple expression for the pdf of $A^2$?) Failing that, is there a reasonable approximation that works for both large and small $N$?

I'm working from this survey of research on related questions:

- Abdi et al. 2000, "On the PDF of the sum of random vectors", IEEE Trans. Commun. **48** (1) 7-12. DOI: [10.1109/26.818866](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/26.818866), free preprint: http://web.njit.edu/~abdi/srv.pdf

I've been wading through the references given on the first page for item (3) and (c) "various analytic approximations", but I haven't found anything satisfactory. It appears to be a hard problem in general. The good news is that I'm interested in fixed amplitudes $A_n$, which should simplify the problem. The bad news is that I'm interested in arbitrary values of the $A_n$. There could be 100 vectors of similar magnitudes, or there could be 1 dominant vector and 5 much smaller vectors, etc. I mention this because some references treat only the case where all of the $A_n$ are equal.

I want to evaluate the pdf millions of times per second, which is one reason why I'm shying away from the integrals in part II of the survey. If the integrals undergo a massive simplification for fixed $A_n$, it's not obvious to me, so please let me know if that's the case!

I'm hoping to use the answer to this question in a Bayesian approach to polyphonic pitch tracking. It would be useful to evaluate the likelihood of an observed filter response arising from a proposed set of tones with specific filtered amplitudes and unknown phases. If there's no great solution, I could fall back to an ugly hack: If $N=2$ then compute the exact solution; if $N>2$ then approximate the distribution of $A$ with a Rayleigh distribution, truncated to the correct support. So, I guess I'm looking for a solution that's a little better than that. For example, it would be great to put peaks in the correct places when $N=3$.